# Do I have too many variables and not enough data points for cluster analysis?

Tags: clustering, underdetermined

I have 75 observations and 152 variables. I want to perform cluster analysis. If I perform cluster analysis and this data will the results be meaningful? Do I need to reduce the number of variables first?

Comment: you could use SVD to determine the transformation that maps to a fully-ranked system 75x75.  There are other method for handling this sort of data.

Comment: It *can* work. But you should verify any results or patterns that you get out carefully, and not assume they are true, just because they were in your data.

Answer (score 2):

There's no rule of the thumb since you can't know in advanced the patterns of information in your data. You should first apply a basic clustering algorithm (such as hierarchical clustering) on your raw (or scaled) dataset and see what that gives you. If you're not happy with the result, you could use a dimensionality reduction technique such as Principal Component Analysis in order to decrease the number of variables by keeping the more informative ones, then re-apply a proper clustering algorithm on the reduced dataset.

If you know what you want to observe, it will be trivial to evaluate emerging patterns as you try out different techniques.